# GoogleJsonResponseException: Field name is required

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics-api, google-apis-explorer

I'm working with the Google Analytics API for the first time and I'm trying to create a new property. I wrote a JS function in Google App Script:

```js
function insertProperty() {
  var resource = 
      {
        //  "accountId": "177832616",
        "resource":{
          "name": "Test Property 7",
          //  "dataRetentionResetOnNewActivity": false,
          "websiteUrl": "https://www.test.com"
        }
      }
  var accountID = '177832616';
  var request = Analytics.Management.Webproperties.insert(resource, accountID);
    
 // request.execute(function (response) { console.log(property.id) });
}
```

This is the error the API throws:

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to analytics.management.webproperties.insert failed with error: Field name is required. (line 56, file "Code")

The `insert()` method seems to take two parameters: `insert(Webproperty resource, string accountId);`

Since it's not recognizing the `name` key/value I added to `resource`, my guess is I haven't declared the variable as a `Webproperty` type and I'm not sure how to do this. I assumed `Webproperty` was a `{ }` variable type, but at this point I'm not sure what to try next. Doing research online, I'm not able to find anything regarding the API's `Webproperty` so any context/info is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, I could understand that Google Analytics API is used with Advanced Google services of Google Apps Script. In this case, `resource` of `Analytics.Management.Webproperties.insert(resource, accountId)` can directly use the request body of the method of "Web Properties: insert". I think that the reason of your error is due to this. So please modify as follows and test it again.

#### From:

```
var resource = 
    {
      //  "accountId": "177832616",
      "resource":{
        "name": "Test Property 7",
        //  "dataRetentionResetOnNewActivity": false,
        "websiteUrl": "https://www.test.com"
      }
    }
```

#### To:

```
var resource = {
  "name": "Test Property 7",
  "websiteUrl": "https://www.test.com"
}
```

#### Note:

- When `accountId` is not correct, an error occurs. Please be careful this.
- From [iansedano's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63891766/googlejsonresponseexception-field-name-is-required/63893315#comment112996420_63893315), in this case, `request` of `var request = Analytics.Management.Webproperties.insert(resource, accountID);` directly returns the values. So you can see the value like `console.log(request)` and `console.log(request.toString())`.

#### Reference:

- [Web Properties: insert](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/webproperties/insert)

Comment: This is spot on, it also doesn't require `request.execute()` 

OP can simply `console.log(request.toString())` after this line:

`var request = Analytics. ...`

Comment: @iansedano Thank you for your comment. I had thought that OP might know that `request` of `var request = Analytics.Management.Webproperties.insert(resource, accountID);` directly returns the values because of the comment line. But from your comment, I thought that your comment will be useful for OP. So I added it. Thank you for your support.

Comment: That change did the trick --- thank you both for your help! Spot on

Comment: @Jessica Feliciano Thank you for your response.